# linux mechanism to measure process memory consumption f

Tags: c, linux, unix, memory-management

what is the most efficient and accurate way/ API to measure heap memory consumption from the same running process programmatically? I want to estimate (as accurately as is reasonably possible) how much memory has been `new` or `malloc` since startup, minus the memory that has been `free` or `delete`

the scope of the question is linux and possibly other linux environments. The language is either C or C++

---

**EDIT**
 It is enough for my purposes to know the actual number (and size) of allocated/held blocks by any `malloc` implementation, i don't need the detail of actual malloc memory minus the the freed memory

Comment: From inside your program (you want it to monitor itself), or outside (you want to monitor a running program)?  For humans (interactive use) or automated?

Comment: from the same process, presumably using the C library

Comment: If you written the code, add wrappers for allocations/deletions and count the bytes...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming new uses malloc look [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc).

For more details of a processes memory allocation, look at the /proc/[pid]/maps.

Also note that linux implements copy-on-write. This means that sometimes processes can share memory. This is especially true if the process was forked without calling exec afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mallinfo](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Statistics-of-Malloc.html) for an estimation. I've just found this, not sure whether this is process or system.. :/

I'm not totally sure what you are asking, malloc minus freed is less than the actual usage because of the memory fragmentation, if you really need that number you have to use custom allocators (which are tiny wrappers around existing ones) *everywhere* in your code which is going to be painful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered reading from /proc/u/stat?  (where "u" is your pid)

Answer (score 0):

If you use valgrind and run your program to completion, it gives you a report on memory usage.

http://valgrind.org/

Comment: sorry my question wasn't clear enough. I meant programmatically from the same running process. I edited to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

You can get quite a bit of information about your heap usage by linking against [tcmalloc from Google Perftools](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/heap_checker.html).  It is designed to locate memory leaks and determine "who the heck allocated all that RAM", but it provides enough instrumentation to answer most questions you might have about your heap.